# A question about solving matrix-optimization problems

Tags: functions, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

Let us assume that $W\in\mathbb{R}^{d\times k}$ and $W\geq 0$. Let us also assume that $f(W)$ is a real-valued function such that
$$f(W)\leq 0,\quad\forall W\in\mathbb{R}^{d\times k},\quad W\geq 0.$$
Furthermore, the function $f$ can be convex or not. What are the ways to solve the following optimization problem?

$$ \min_{W \in\mathbb{R}^{d\times k},W \geq 0} f(w) $$

P.S. We know that if $f$ is convex, then it has a unique minimum. However, it is possible that the function $f(W)$ is not convex.

Comment: This is really too broad of a question to get a reasonable answer.

Comment: What does $\geq 0$ denote?

Comment: @Rodrigo de Azevedo, Thank you so much for your comment. This means that all elements of W are non-negative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I apologize if I'm misunderstanding the question.  If you're asking how to do this numerically, then:

(1) Choose a programming language that you prefer

(2) Create mapping routines from $\rm R^{d \times k}$ to $\rm R^m$ where $m = d \times k$ and vice versa.  I.e. if $f(W)$ is nonlinear, there's not a huge benefit in keeping the structure of $W$.

(3) Optimize, e.g. using fmin in Python https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.fmin.html

(4) Drop solutions where $W < 0$.  Or if you prefer, add a penalty to your $f(W)$ function when elements of $W$ are $< 0$, e.g. $exp(-w^2)$.

(5) If you must maintain $W>0$ for the entire search, choose one of the functions in  https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/optimize.html that allows for bounds.

Comment: I am very thankful for the information you provided. I have a question. You mentioned that "Drop solutions where W<0." I have been thinking about this point mentioned by you for a long time in matters related to my field of work. In matrix optimization problems, such as the one mentioned above, where we need the solution matrix to be a non-negative matrix, is there no problem if we discard its negative elements? In fact, after discarding the negative elements of the obtained answer, can we still expect that this obtained matrix is a suitable approximation of the optimal solution?

Comment: There is no single correct answer to your comment above.  You've already indicated the function $f(w)$ is unlikely to be convex, and hence $W_{min}$ is unlikely to be unique.  If you're fitting experimental work, I recommend reading Data Analysis; A Bayesian Tutorial, D. S. Silva, Oxford Press (2006).  If it's purely numerical, look up Sensitivity Analysis https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance-based_sensitivity_analysis to better understand your inverse space.

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation you gave in answer to my question. I think your argument is quite logical. I had already reached some of what you mentioned before, but I was not sure about my findings. In addition, the references you mentioned will be very helpful, thank you. Now, if the function f(W) is convex, is your argument still correct? In fact, can we discard the negative elements of W? Thank you for your time.

Comment: I didn't say eliminate the negative elements of $W$, while keeping the positive elements of $W$.  I wrote discard solutions with $W < 0$ where you have defined $W < 0$ if $w_{ij} < 0$.  The difference is subtle as I will explain below.   If the problem is convex then there should exist one and only one $W$ that minimizes $f(W)$, right?  If $W$ has elements that are < 0 (which we've defined to mean W < 0) AND the problem is convex then you have some more fundamental problem in your formulation OR it's due to numerical noise.  I could imagine both being issues during your research.

Comment: The analogous problem in 1-D is that for solving the parabolic quadratic motion of an object, e.g. for the time when it hits the ground.  https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/132821/what-do-negative-times-and-negative-displacements-represent-in-parametric-projec .   Only the positive root is useful to solve the problem, although in the case I am sighting here there is a physically meaningful negative root.  In many physical problems the negative and/or imaginary roots are not necessarily meaningful.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response to my question, and for providing such a piece of complete information about my challenges. I now fully understand what you mean. Thanks a lot.